# C# Linq - Order by ASC starting from VALUE

Tags: c#, linq

I have an int array, and I want to order by the values in ascending order starting from a certain value, which we'll call `startValue`. However, I want to retain all the values, and the ones which are greater than `startValue` should appear *after* the maximum value in the list.

This is probably easier to explain with an example...

```
int[] values = new int[] { 1, 2, 4, 6, 9 };
int startValue = 4;
int[] orderedValues = { 4, 6, 9, 1, 2 }; // desired result
```

How can I achieve this? I thought something like this would do the trick, but it leaves the order of the new `orderedValues` the same as the original values.

```
int[] orderedValues = values.OrderBy( v => v >= startValue ).ToArray();
```

Comment: "but it leaves the original values array unaltered" - yes, LINQ is designed for *querying* rather than modifying the original data. Is there any reason you don't want to just use the result of the ordering? You could always copy that into `values` afterwards if you really wanted. (I suspect you want `OrderBy(v => v >= startValue).ThenBy(v => v)` by the way.)

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry, edited my question for clarity. I meant the order of the new array was the same as the original one. I've just tried your suggestion, and it seems to also leave the order the same as the original. Perhaps I'm missing something? `int[] orderedValues = values.OrderBy( v => v >= startValue ).ThenBy( v => v ).ToArray(); // still 1,2,4,6,9`

Comment: Your LINQ expression implies that you'll only order the values that are higher than 4...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems with your current code:

- You're *only* ordering by whether or not the value is at least `startValue`, not by the values themselves (the "in ascending order" part)
- `false` is ordered before `true`, so you need to reverse your condition

Here's an example that works fine:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int[] values = new int[] { 1, 2, 4, 6, 9 };
        int startValue = 4;
        int[] orderedValues = values
            .OrderBy(v => v < startValue) // Note reversed comparison
            .ThenBy(v => v)               // Order by value within each segment
            .ToArray();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", orderedValues));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

Split your `values` in two groups and sort them separately. After this you can join this groups with `Concat`. Try this code:

```
var result = values
    .Where(v => v >= startValue) // filter first group
    .OrderBy(v => v)
    .Concat(
      values.Where(v => v < startValue).OrderBy(v => v) // second group
    )
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: I had though about this (although my code wasnt as elegant as your example), but the idea seems overly cumbersome. The end result is correct, but I was hoping it might be possible to do with some nifty order criteria

Comment: @Klicker so you are looking for solution with single `OrderBy` and smart lambda?

Comment: I had thought one `OrderBy` clause would do the trick, but Jon's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55011353/6236042) points out the use of `ThenBy`, which is required because there two order conditions required.

Answer (score -1):

```
 int[] values = new int[] { 1, 2, 4, 6, 9 };
            int startValue = 4;
            int[] orderedValues = { 4, 6, 9, 1, 2 }; 

        var a = from v in values
                where v >= startValue orderby v
                select v;
        orderedValues = a.ToArray();
```

Comment: Unfortunately because you are applying a `where` clause, any data that does not meet your condition will be excluded from the result. So numbers `1, 2` are not in your `orderedValues` array, because they are less than `startValue`. I want them to be included, but come after the maximum value in the array.